# Call Controller from .cshtml via getJSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have performed this action within a .js file without issue and I am wondering if I have to do something a little different from a .cshtml because I can't seem to find any other reason this is failing.  Here is my js within my .cshtml file:

```
mergeBtn.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = '/api/publicpatron/student-no-validation?studentNo=' + studentNo.value;

    $.getJSON(url)
    .done(function (json) {
        if (json.errors) {
            toastr.error(json.message, '', { timeOut: 0, extendedTimeOut: 0 })
        }
        else {
            //do something
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus = ', ' + error;
        toastr.error(err, '', { timeOut: 0, extendedTimeOut: 0 })
    })
}
```

The code in the controller doesn't seem to be the issue as it never gets to the controller, I have verified I have the controller file name and function name correct in my URL.  Any suggestions? Is this not possible from within a .cshtml file??

UPDATE:

Here is the controller:

file name: PublicPatronController

```
[Authorize(Roles = "my-roles")]
[ActionName("student-no-validation")]
public dynamic IsStudentNoValid([FromUri] string studentNo)
{
    dynamic results = new ExpandoObject();

    if (studentNo == null)
    {
        results.error = true;
        results.message = "Invalid Student Number";

        return results;
    }

    using (ADRoutineEntities db = new ADRoutineEntities())
    {
        var exists = db.UserLinkages.Any(x => x.StudentNo == studentNo);
        if (!exists)
        {
            results.errors = true;
            results.message = string.Format("Student number {0} does not exist", studentNo);

            return results;
        }
    }

    results.ok = true;

    return results;
}
```

UPDATE 2:
It does appear to be related to the controller somehow.  I changed the url to a different `apicontroller` I use elsewhere and it worked fine.  The issue seems to be related to the name of the `apicontroller`.  When I change it to the name of an existing `apicontroller` but keep the `actionname` the same it works.  Why would that be???

Comment: Please show the controller, that fact that is never reaching it means that the problem can be in there

Comment: added the controller

Comment: FWIW, An API controller should be returning `404` or `500` errors, not using a `dynamic` with `errors`/`message`. HTTP already has a method of giving feedback, why deviate?

Comment: Have you verified that the javascript is called at all. If you have not actually selected the object `mergeBtn` then the onclick event will not be applied

Comment: the onclick fires, the .getJSON request fails with error "Method Not Allowed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `[HttpGet]`-attribute to the method on the controller.

Normally WebAPI takes the first part of the methodname to determine what HTTP-verb it should use. In your case, that's not a valid http-method, so you need to explicitly add the attribute.

Another option is to change the method name, eg: `GetIsStudentNoValid`

You should also return an HttpResponseMessage with a status code instead of a `dynamic`

Comment: 1 million thanks to you sir!! I was bashing my head against my desk trying to figure it out.  That makes complete sense and solved my issue!